# Excel Javascript Add-in Deployment On Local Network

Tags: javascript, excel, deployment, localhost, yeoman

I have developed an Excel Javascript Add-in on my machine using the yeoman generator. The add-in itself works fine when I start it up on my client with npm start. I can use the add-in on any port I want provided I change all the ports in the config files etc. However, we now want to delpoy this add-in on our local server to make it available to several users.

1. I have noticed that every time I change the location of the project e.g. from my machine to the server the application will start up but Excel will give me the error message "ADD-IN ERROR Sorry, we can't load the add-in. Please make sure you have network and/or Internet connectivity. Click "Retry" once you are back online". My work around for now is to create a new app on the server and copy the html, js and css file to the taskpane folder. When I now start up the new app it'll work fine.
2. For the second issue I haven't found a solution/understood the behaviour. When I create an app with the yeoman generator on our server (MS server 2019) and start it up it can be reached via e.g. localhost:3000 on the server but not via :3000 or :3000. It runs fine when I access it from the server itself.

I have opened the inbound and outbound port 3000 on the server to allow https communication. In a next step I added the manifest to the windows 365 admin console and added myself as user. When I open Excel from my machine (client side) the excel add-in will be available in the insert ribbon but won't load and I get the same error message as described above "ADD-IN ERROR Sorry, we can't load the add-in. Please make sure you have network and/or Internet connectivity. Click "Retry" once you are back online"

The following *troubleshooting* steps have been performed. I checked whether I can reach the add-in url via web browser but the connection timed out. When I check on the server side whether the app is listening I get the below result.

**TCP  127.0.0.1:3000 0.0.0.0 Listening 40776**

I'm not sure but I think the app should list on e.g. 0.0.0.0:3000 to capture inbound traffic from the client side. Is there a way to change this add-in (app) behaviour on the server when creating/starting up the app with the yeoman generator? I have checked the webpack.config.js file but I couldn't find any way to change that behaviour.

Any idea/help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is precisely the intended configuration of the yeoman development environment.  It spins up the webpack dev (NodeJS) server, which by default only listens to the localhost / loopback address.

From here:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhost

It looks like you could hand modify your webpack.config.js file to include a
host: '0.0.0.0' entry under the devServer listing.

The other item you might need to change is
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverallowedhosts

As I believe this defaults to 'auto' which would only allow connections from the local computer.